# How to get dynamically generated X86_64 to return a value relative to the RIP / RBP

Tags: c, assembly, code-generation, x86-64

I'm trying to read values in memory relative to the `%rip` on X86_64. In my first example I just want to read

If I write the following code in C, I can call it and get the correct result (`\x....C3C9`):

```
void * test() {
    __asm("mov 0(%rip), %rax");
}
```

The generated code looks as follows:

```
0000000000400624 <test>:
  400624:   55                      push   %rbp
  400625:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400628:   48 8b 05 00 00 00 00    mov    0x0(%rip),%rax        # 40062f <test+0xb>
  40062f:   c9                      leaveq 
  400630:   c3                      retq
```

If I now however put this code directly in memory and execute it I get a segfault, while I would expect to read `\x0000C3C9`:

```
int main()
{
    int codesize = 9;
    unsigned char * code = (unsigned char*)malloc(1024);
    memcpy(code, "\x48\x8B\x5\x0\x0\x0\x0\xC9\xC3\x00\x00", codesize + 2);
    mprotect(code, codesize, PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ);
    goto *code;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

*edit*
The answer is that I shouldn't have used `malloc` but `mmap` to allocate a page-aligned memory region:

```
(unsigned char*)mmap(NULL, 1024, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
```

And of course I should have checked the return value of the call to `mprotect`. It returned -1 flagging that it had failed.

Comment: I got a comment by somebody who deleted his comment again, however he lead me in the right direction. He was right that `mprotect` is failing (stupid me, I should have checked). I guess `malloc` (obviously) doesn't return memory aligned to the page boundary. By using `(unsigned char*)mmap(NULL, 1024, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);` it does work.

Comment: If you add `PROT_EXEC` to the `mmap` call, you wouldn't need `mprotect`.

Comment: I didn't do it since I read somewhere that some kernels disallow having it `PROT_WRITE` and `PROT_EXEC` at the same time. Did I misunderstand it?

Comment: Hmm, perhaps they do, though I would consider that a bug...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PaX#Restricted_mprotect.28.29

Comment: @tverwaes: From that, it sounds like PaX makes it impossible to do this at all. `w+x` is forbidden anytime, and adding `x` to an existing page that wasn't already `x` is forbidden... Lovely...

Answer (score 1):

You most likely get the SIGSEGV during the mprotect() call. If the code execution of the memory returned by malloc() is disallowed by the OS (it most likely is if you aren't using some ancient kernel), mprotect() just segfaults. That's not a bug, it's a feature.

Comment: `mprotect` will not segfault. In reality it will succeed, but if it couldn't succeed, it will return -1 and set `errno`.

Comment: Actually it will if the argument isn't page aligned, but it will return an error, not a segfault. The subsequent code then segfaults.

Comment: Yes exactly, this was the problem as far as I can tell. I just used to use static strings instead of `malloc`ing, and that seemed to work. I guess static strings are page-aligned but `malloc`ed strings aren't.

Comment: Just started this program with gdb, and it segfaults after the return of mprotect(), even if I fill in some harmless code after mprotect(). Anyway, mprotect() should not used with malloc(), only with mmap()

Comment: Oh strange. Here it never segfaulted after the `mprotect`. I did put `printf`s. But you are right, I should use `mmap` :)

Answer (score 0):

the `ret` instruction is basically a `pop value from the stack; goto value`.

When you `goto <your_code>`, `ret` eventually gets executed the problem is that you have garbage on the stack (maybe the `ret` instruction tries to `goto 9` because codesize is the variable on the top of the stack, who knows...).

Basically, it doesn't work because you are using your asm snippet incorrectly.

May I ask what you are trying to do ? I could help :)

---

A test program to get your rip:

```
static inline unsigned long get_rip(void)
{
    unsigned long val;
    asm volatile(
        "call 1f\n"
        "1: popq %0\n"
        : "=r"(val));
    return val;
}

int main()
{
    printf("rip = %p\n", (void *)get_rip());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would there be garbage on the stack? When I `goto <my_code>` I didn't touch the stack yet, so I'm just running it as if it were directly within the `main` function. I'm working on a Smalltalk -> ASM compiler (written in Smalltalk) since I'd like to get rid of virtual machines altogether. X86_64 seems like a good place to start. Lots to learn, but lots of fun :)

Comment: Posted a code snippet to show you how to get the rip value :)

Comment: The `leaveq` instruction before the `retq` should leave the stack pointer pointing at the return address from `main()`, assuming `main()` used a normal function prologue.

Comment: Right, since my code is supposed to run within code I generate myself the prologues will be exactly what I expect. This obviously will not work if you start doing optimizations in GCC for example. Good hint ;)